# Is it useful to save captured photo into internal directory to put is later in HashMap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My thinking:

Is it useful to shot and save a photo into internal directory or `MODE.PRIVATE` and use the file to save it on `Bitmap` and then from `Bitmap` to `Base64` `String`?

I'm made this code to save an Image into private app directory.

```
pictureActionIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imageFolder = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath()+"/img/");
File image = new File(imageFolder,taskItems.get("uuid")+".jpg");

Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

My aim is the `Base64` `String` that I want to put it on a `HashMap<String,String>`.

And if yes, how can I do it?

Thanks for help!

Kind Regards!

Comment: why would you want to store it in a hashmap? why not store in sQlite instead? so that you wont loose it when the JVM is restarted!\

Comment: because i overwrite a whole tag in a xml file with the map. thats the reason why i'm using a hashmap